Help Enhance Warp Exit Sound Effect – Need More Depth and Volume
I'm working on a sound effect for a sci-fi project, specifically the moment a spaceship exits a warp jump. I've created a base effect (link to the file is attached), but I feel like it's missing depth and that immersive, cinematic "oomph" that makes the scene pop.
The core sound is there, but I need help making it feel larger, more atmospheric, and truly "out of this world." Ideally, it should have:
A sharper, more impactful initial burst or pop.
A deeper, resonant low-end rumble.
A more spacious and immersive reverb effect.
If anyone has suggestions for tweaks, plugins, or layering techniques, I’d greatly appreciate your input. If you’re willing to directly work with the file, please let me know!
Thanks in advance for your help – looking forward to hearing your ideas!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Omc_q1Y6avFRhZEChr5_wEBDshyVf2Ti/view?usp=drive_link

I'll just add some things to think about - call it "sound design theory". It's up to you to develop those into the enhancement you're looking for, if you wish.
As a sound designer, there is always an inherent problem with warp jumps and other space-scenes, which actually naturally hold you back from certain avenues and push you down others.
What I mean is this; Sound does not travel in space. So there should be no sound at all from the viewer's perspective. But that would not seem "right". Why? Because we don't spend any time in space, so are not used to the physics of a setting with no atmosphere and if you've ever seen a warp jump, unless you have some BIG secret, it was on TV/film and probably had sound - a big sound - which reinforces that bias. This is the same reason why real video footage of Moon dust flicked up by a Moon buggy wheel, or tethers flexing on a spacecraft in low Earth orbit, can seem kinda... "fake", which you don't want in a movie. So it's all about a "realistic" experience through expectation.
So we must fulfil the viewer's expectation, even if it is not really factual, because viewer immersion is everything. Another physical property that we are good at "expecting" is resonance. If you were watching a movie and somebody tapped a musical triangle or a small bell and below the high "ting" is a very low "BONNNG!" - your suspicion meter would instantly take you away from the moment, because your experience tells you that small things do not resonate at very low frequencies - just as small rooms don't naturally resonate like a cathedral. It's expectation and immersion in a realistic setting.
So, we have a ship in infinite open space. That limits our ability to use bright reflective resonance to beef up our sound, as there are no secondary surfaces to reflect sound.
But what if we change our listening perspective?
If we change our perspective to the people on the ship, then we can imagine what they would hear and use that as a guide. Have you ever been on a starship at warp? Well, luckily, I have (shhh!), and it sounds a lot like being in a submarine or a large ship going through some extreme tidal stresses, whaling and creaking resonant harmonics filtered by the environment - the ship itself. Imagine the softened screaming metallic harmonic resonances of something big and solid like a HUGE submarine being put through extremes of physics. So think about what kind of resonant sound the ship would make if stretched and contorted in spacetime like a bell being deformed, condensed down to a burst like a sonic boom. That resonant frequency will help allude to the size of the ship - and will change as it distorts. And as space folds and flexes, you can follow that with rapid pitch shifts or cutoff modulation. High distorted resonance of the filter can give a futuristic watery wobble.
So what's wrong with what you have?
Well, for a start, it sounds like it's an initial warp jump, not an exit. You need there to be a general downward settling of "wild" pitches, not upward.
It's too far "forward". It's just too dry. You need that resonance to ring through, modulated and filtered down as it would be if you were onboard. You could try some very short spacial delay (L/R) or some other extreme widening method to wet it up (check for mono issues). This will give a bigger spacial effect without using reverb.
It's too long. What would be creating that trailing sound? You need to think physics. Often with futuristic impacts in space, shorter is more "realistic". If you're going to have something trail off, it should be a resonant decay.
Moving forward
You need to watch videos of large stressful impacts and listen to what trails off and what stops and the relationship of amplitude, pitch and filtering over time for them (Envelopes!). As a pro-tip, I would say try out a modulator-carrier type of band-modulation like a Vocoder to bring a common low rippling pitch-modulated "ring". That ripping distorted sound like a jet-sound "ripping" H2O molecules from the air via extreme pressures is very exciting too. Remember, you want to give the impression you are tearing through the fabric of spacetime!

Thank you very much for the advice and for answering my question, to be honest, this is the longest text I have read this week. I probably won't be able to write for so long, so I'll just say thank you. I also want to add that it was especially interesting to read about how there is no air and there simply can't be any sound. The issue of the effect of the ship exiting the warp jump has been resolved.
